# jquery, wrap an element in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="top">

   <span id="innter"></span> Here may have a lot of different div, span


</div>
```

What I want to do is wrap the span by another div element.

So it looks like this:

```
<div id="top">
   <div id="wrapper">
       <span id="innter"></span>
    </div
</div>
```

What is the best way to do this?
I found wrapAll() is useful, but not sure how to include all the elements inside #top.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap) method

```
$('#innter').wrap('<div id="wrapper" />');
```

Comment: Indeed, I was careless and have not seen the "include all the elements inside #top".

Answer (score 2):

You can use `wrapInner` or

```
var content = $("#top").html();
$("#top").html("<div id='wrapper'>"+content+"</div>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use try this:

```
 $('#top').wrapInner('<div id="wrapper" />');
```