# Using jQuery: Wrapping div in another div with .before()

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to add a div around the following code:

```
<div class="fsSubField">
<input id="field15744501-zip" class="fsField fsFieldZip fsFormatZipCA" type="text" value="" size="8" name="field15744501-zip">
<br>
<label class="fsSupporting" for="field15744501-zip">Postal Code</label>
</div>
```

So that in the end I have:

```
<div class="fsSubFieldGroup" style="margin-top:5px;">
<div class="fsSubField">
<input id="field15744501-zip" class="fsField fsFieldZip fsFormatZipCA" type="text" value="" size="8" name="field15744501-zip">
<br>
<label class="fsSupporting" for="field15744501-zip">Postal Code</label>
</div>
</div>
```

I tried the following:

```
$('input.fsFormatZipCA').parent().before('<div> class="fsSubFieldGroup" style="margin-top:5px;">');
$('input.fsFormatZipCA').parent().after('</div>');
```

Because of the dynamic nature of the form I need to be able to base the select on 'input.fsFormatZipCA'

I would think this would work but the problem is that jQuery is doing the following:

```
<div class="fsSubFieldGroup" style="margin-top: 5px;"></div>
<div class="fsSubField">
<input id="field15744501-zip" class="fsField fsFieldZip fsFormatZipCA" type="text" value="" size="8" name="field15744501-zip">
<br>
<label class="fsSupporting" for="field15744501-zip">Postal Code</label>
</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery, wrap an element in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314412/jquery-wrap-an-element-in-a-div) and [many many others](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=jquery+wrap+element).

Comment: `.before()` and `.after()` are *DOM manipulation methods*. They are for inserting DOM nodes, they don't before string concatenation or make changes to the source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be looking for `.wrap`:

```
$('input.fsFormatZipCA').parent().wrap(
  $('<div>', {
    'class': 'fsSubFieldGroup',  // class is a reserved word
    css: {
      'margin-top': 5  // - is an invalid identifier character
    }
  })
);
```

`.before` inserts an *element* before an element. It does not construct the HTML by plainly prepending an HTML string.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.wrap()`:

```
$('input.fsFormatZipCA').parent().wrap('<div class="fsSubFieldGroup" style="margin-top:5px;">');
```

More info in the jQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/wrap/

---

*Sidenote: You maybe notice that the `.wrap()` function adds hte `</div>` for you. It makes stuff a lot easier.*

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
$('.fsFormatZipCA').parent().wrap('<div class="fsSUbFieldGroup" />');
```